# Class that acts as mapping for **unpacking

Tags: python, class, mapping, argument-unpacking

Without subclassing dict, what would a class need to be considered a mapping so that it can be passed to a method with `**`.

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class uobj:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

uobj.register(dict)

def f(**k): return k

o = uobj()
f(**o)

# outputs: f() argument after ** must be a mapping, not uobj
```

At least to the point where it throws errors of missing functionality of mapping, so I can begin implementing.

I reviewed emulating container types but simply defining magic methods has no effect, and using `ABCMeta` to override and register it as a dict validates assertions as subclass, but fails `isinstance(o, dict)`. Ideally, I dont even want to use `ABCMeta`.

Comment: For Python3 see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71145561/4019836

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The `__getitem__()` and `keys()` methods will suffice:

```
>>> class D:
        def keys(self):
            return ['a', 'b']
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return key.upper()


>>> def f(**kwds):
        print kwds


>>> f(**D())
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 34):

If you're trying to create a Mapping — not just satisfy the requirements for passing to a function — then you really should inherit from `collections.abc.Mapping`.  As described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc), you need to implement just:

```
__getitem__
__len__
__iter__
```

The Mixin will implement everything else for you:  `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__`.

Comment: beyond the scope, but has relevance and is informative, thankyou

Comment: Useful. This has now moved to the collections.abc package here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc

Comment: @StuartBuckingham I appreciate your modesty, but please just feel free to edit my answer next time :)

Comment: Ahhh I didn't realize that was possible. Thanks @NeilG

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found by digging through the source.

When attempting to use a non-mapping object with `**`, the following error is given:

```
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not a mapping
```

If we search CPython's source for that error, we can find [the code that causes that error to be raised](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6cc800d3634fdd002b986c3ffe6a3d5540f311a0/Python/ceval.c#L3362):

```
case TARGET(DICT_UPDATE): {
    PyObject *update = POP();
    PyObject *dict = PEEK(oparg);
    if (PyDict_Update(dict, update) < 0) {
        if (_PyErr_ExceptionMatches(tstate, PyExc_AttributeError)) {
            _PyErr_Format(tstate, PyExc_TypeError,
                            "'%.200s' object is not a mapping",
                            Py_TYPE(update)->tp_name);
```

[`PyDict_Update` is actually `dict_merge`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/21dd43c01d6b9cd50512c9ab6d83c97cde3bf115/Objects/dictobject.c#L2612), and the error is thrown when `dict_merge` returns a negative number. If we [check the source for `dict_merge`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/21dd43c01d6b9cd50512c9ab6d83c97cde3bf115/Objects/dictobject.c#L2434), we can see what leads to -1 being returned:

```
/* We accept for the argument either a concrete dictionary object,
 * or an abstract "mapping" object.  For the former, we can do
 * things quite efficiently.  For the latter, we only require that
 * PyMapping_Keys() and PyObject_GetItem() be supported.
 */
if (a == NULL || !PyDict_Check(a) || b == NULL) {
    PyErr_BadInternalCall();
    return -1;
```

The key part being:

> For the latter, we only require that PyMapping_Keys() and PyObject_GetItem() be supported.

Comment: does this mean only __getitem__ and keys need to be defined for ti

Comment: @Max It's more than a year later, so I don't remember all I previously discovered, but yes, that's what the comment suggests. That finding is also mirrored in the top answer. I posted this answer as a way to show how something like this could be found.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using dataclasses

Cleaner and ultimatelly turns out to be better in terms of quality, the usage of dataclass, which helps also return the correct object to `keys` method.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    surname: str
    age: int
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def keys(self):
        return self.__annotations__.keys()


josh_doe: Person = Person("John", "Doe", 31)
print(f"John object : {josh_doe}")
user_data = {**josh_doe}
print(user_data)
```