# How to test if object is a mapping (supports **O usage)

Tags: python, mapping

I need to test if objects read in from a file (and `eval`ed) with `ConfigParser` are mappings.

Not entirely sure about the terminology here, but let me explain. Given that my object is called `O` it must support being used in the following manner:

```
def tester(**kwargs):
     print kwargs

tester(**O)
```

If `O` was not supporting the ** this would result in a TypeError, e.g. `TypeError: test() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple`.

It's a really simple scenario, but I need to know that `O` will work before using it and I need to be absolutely certain it won't fail. If I was testing `O` for being an iterable, I would use something like:

```
try:
   iter(O)
except:
   O = tuple()
```

As discussed in [In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable/1952481#1952481)

I can't find any parallel for mappings. As discussed in the same answer above, using `isinstance` and `collections` isn't an good solution.

So do I have to make my tester-function above (without the print) as my own mapping-test when loading the objects like

```
try:
    tester(**O)
except TypeError:
    O = {}
```

or does python have a built in way to test this like there is for iterables? It seems there should be one.

**Edit**

Actually the linked answer above never spoke against the isinstance method, should have read it better...

Comment: See also [python-custom-mapping-class-unpacking-and-keys-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33547061/7038689) - interesting discussion about how the `**kwarg`-style unpacking requires a method explicitly named `keys` that returns an iterable list, along with `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`collections.abc.Mapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) ABC:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

if isinstance(O, Mapping):
    # O is a mapping
```

This supports any object that implements the right *methods* to be considered a mapping, including `dict`.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Mapping
>>> isinstance({}, Mapping)
True
>>> isinstance((), Mapping)
False
```

Comment: But it must be derived from Mapping or something being a mapping, is this truely the same thing as supporting the ** ?

Comment: @deinonychusaur: No, `Mapping` is a ABC, an abstract base class, and any object supporting the *methods* is considered an instance. It doesn't actually need to inherit from `Mapping`, implementing the functionality is enough.

Comment: OK thanks for the quick reply, I was only confused it seems, but python mapping-concept seems not so present here on SO hopefully it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 7):

Some objects may not be instances of `collections.Mapping` and yet can be unpacked using double-star syntax(`**`):

```
import collections
def tester(**kwargs):
     print kwargs

class D:
    "http://stackoverflow.com/a/8601389/190597 (Raymond Hettinger)"
    def keys(self):
        return ['a', 'b']
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key.upper()

obj = D()
tester(**obj)
# {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}

print(isinstance(obj, collections.Mapping))
# False
```

The minimal interface that `obj` must supply is `keys` and `__getitem__`:

```
print(all(hasattr(obj, attr) for attr in ('keys', '__getitem__')))
# True
```

Comment: So you are saying is that the only true way of knowing is of testing, or potentially using `dir` (though that would be lower degree of confidence)?

Comment: No, I'm saying when `all(hasattr(obj, attr) for attr in ('keys', '__getitem__'))` is `True`, then `tester(**obj)` works.

Comment: @unutbu More precisely, the criteria is `hasattr(obj, 'keys') and hasattr(type(obj), '__getitem__')`. The `keys` can be either a method on the object's class or a just a callable attribute on the object, but the `__getitem__` magic method *must* be a method on the object's class, since `obj[key]` looks for it on the class, not on the object. If you test for `__getitem__` on the object itself, you could get a false positive from the test and an `TypeError: ... object is not subscriptable` from `**obj`.