# What does a class need to implement in order to be used as an argument tuple?

Tags: python, arguments

I want to be able to do something like the following

```
class C(object):
     # I store a series of values in some way
     # what do I need to implement to act like an array of arguments


c=C()
result=f(*c)
```

What does the `*`"operator" invoke on the instance in this usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to control the behavior of the `*` operator when it is used like that:

1. Overload the [`__iter__` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__):

   ```
   >>> class C(object):
   ...     def __init__(self, lst):
   ...         self.lst = lst
   ...     def __iter__(self):
   ...         return iter(self.lst)
   ...
   >>> def f(a, b, c):
   ...     print "Arguments: ", a, b, c
   ...
   >>> c = C([1, 2, 3])
   >>> f(*c)
   Arguments:  1 2 3
   >>>
   ```
2. Overload the [`__getitem__` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

   ```
   >>> class C(object):
   ...     def __init__(self, lst):
   ...         self.lst = lst
   ...     def __getitem__(self, key):
   ...         return self.lst[key]
   ...
   >>> def f(a, b, c):
   ...     print "Arguments: ", a, b, c
   ...
   >>> c = C([1, 2, 3])
   >>> f(*c)
   Arguments:  1 2 3
   >>>
   ```

Comment: A sequence object will also work (implementing `__getitem__`).

Answer (score 1):

People call this ["positional expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323312/145400)" or argument unpacking. Your instance should provide an `__iter__` method, which is called when iterating over this object. However, I think the cleanest approach would be to subclass [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable), which is the abstract base class for all iterables in Python.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601268/python-class-that-acts-as-mapping-for-unpacking) is the same question for keyword argument unpacking, requiring the object to be a mapping.

Edit: I am still trying to find the exact implementation in this case to see which C API call is used for unpacking. This would yield the precise answer to this question. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is to subclass `tuple` or `list`.