# Override dict() on class

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator, overriding

I'm trying to make a `dict`-like class in Python.

When you make a class, you have certain methods that tell Python how to make a built-in class. For example, overriding the `__int__` method tells Python what to return if the user uses `int()` on an instance of the class. Same for `__float__`. You can even control how Python would make an iterable object of the class by overriding the `__iter__` method (which can help Python make `list`s and `tuple`s of your class). My question is how would you tell Python how to make a `dict` of your custom class? There is no special `__dict__` method, so how would you go about doing it? I want something like the following:

```
class Foo():
    def __dict__(self):
        return {
            'this': 'is',
            'a': 'dict'
        }

foo = Foo()
dict(foo) # would return {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dict'}
```

I've tried making the class inherit from `dict`, but it raises an error later in the code because of subclasses trying to inherit from `dict` and `type`, so inheriting from `dict` isn't a possibility. Is there any other way to do it?

Also, I've overridden the `__iter__` method already so that it would return a `dict_keyiterator` object (what gets returned when you use `iter()` on a `dict`), but it still doesn't seem to work how it should.

Comment: Have you tried inheriting from `collections.abc.*Mapping` yet?

Comment: `collections.abc.Mapping` is a class of `ABCMeta`. A lot of my code was already built on top of the `type` metaclass, so a lot of it isn't compatible with `ABCMeta`. I could go through all my code trying to change it to work with `ABCMeta`, but I was just hoping there might be an easier way that doesn't rely on an abstract class like `Mapping`.

Comment: Just add a `@staticmethod` to your class, named something like `to_dict` for example, which you can explicitly call it to make the dictionary. i.e. `result = foo_obj.to_dict()`.

Comment: There is that workaround, but it seems like there should be an easier way to have Python natively convert a class to a `dict` considering there are `__int__`, `__str__`, and `__iter__` methods. I may have to resort to this, but it just seems more hack-ish than a regular `__dict__` method.

Comment: Using your analogy, I think it might be clearer to think "You can even control how Python would make an *iterable object* from the class by overriding the `__iter__` method." `dict`s are iterables, and like lists and tuples you can create them by passing in iterators.

Comment: @martineau, I don't think you'd want to use `@staticmethod` in this case, would you? Presumably your `to_dict` would need access to an instance in order to convert its attributes to a dictionary.

Comment: @ForeverWintr You're right. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Ah. in that case I think @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams' suggestion is what you need. If you're unable to use `ABCMeta`, you can implement the `mapping` interface yourself. But why can't you inherit from `abc.Mapping`? Are you calling `type` explicitly?

Comment: I'm overriding the `__setattr__` method on my class. Once my script has finished executing, all the code inside the `__setattr__` method works fine. If something tries to get an attribute _before_ it's finished executing though, some errors are raised because the code references pointers that don't exist yet. If I inherit from `ABCMeta`, some code inside the `abc` module is trying to get an attribute from the class, so it's raising an error. I've tried fixing it already to work with `ABCMeta`, but then there's other `__instancecheck__` problems and the code just starts falling apart after that

Comment: I _kind of_ found an answer though by making a `keys` method on my class. If you use `dict` on a class, it'll try to get create a mapping first with the `keys()` method. I got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601389/6212261 It doesn't use the `__iter__` method, so I can implement my own `__iter__` method _and still_ be able to make a `dict` with the same class.

Comment: ForeverWintr: Sorry...when I wrote that comment I meant a `@classmethod` which would have meant the function would need to be passed the object to operate upon, so calls to it would look like `result = Foo.to_dict(foo_obj)`—however you're right, it would be better to just make it a regular method, so calls could simply be something like `result = foo_obj.to_dict()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) can be called with an iterable of pairs, so if you design your `__iter__` to return an iterable of tuples, your example works as you'd like:

```
class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from {
            'this': 'is',
            'a': 'dict'
        }.items()

dict(Foo())
{'a': 'dict', 'this': 'is'}
```

---

If you want your class to behave like a python dictionary, in that iterating over an instance iterates over its keys, you can implement the interface defined by [`abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

You can do this either by implementing `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`, and inheriting from `abc.Mapping`, or by implementing all of `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`  `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__`.

Comment: That does work correctly for creating a `dict` on the `Foo` object, but then you can't iterate through the keys of the items. Something like `for i in Foo()` wouldn't iterate through the _keys_ of the object, it would iterate through a _tuple_ of `(key, value)` tuples.

Comment: @Christian: Good point...however class `Foo` isn't a formal subclass of `dict`, so assuming it will behave exactly like one when it's iterated isn't completely reasonable.

Comment: ForeverWintr: FWIW, giving your class (just) a `__getitem__()` method would also allow built-in `dict` class objects to be created from instances of them. I still think it would be better to be more explicit and give the class a `to_dict()` method instead of relying on the somewhat obscure construction argument details of another class..

Comment: ForeverWintr: As proof try replacing your `__iter__()` method with `def __getitem__(self, key):`, followed by `return [('this', 'is'), ('a', 'dict')][key]`—this makes it behave a little like a `list` of (key, value) pairs.

Comment: @martineau: Ah, of course! That's probably a better answer. Care to add it?

Comment: and re: to_dict(), I agree explicit is often preferable. But plumbing the depths of the language to answer these questions is interesting.

Comment: ForeverWintr: Agree completely about it being an interesting dive into the details of the language—but readability and maintainability shouldn't be thrown out the window as a result.

Answer (score 4):

Although the approach in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627087/355230) from @ForeverWintr is fairly clever and works, I think it's a little obscure since it takes advantage of some of the arcane details about the attributes of the argument passed to the `dict` class constructor.

For that reason a better approach might be what I was saying in my comments about just adding a method that does what you want (plus shows how simply giving it a name indicating exactly what's going on makes it more understandable).

Example code:

```
class Foo:
    def to_dict(self):
        return {'this': 'is', 'more': 'clear'}

print( Foo().to_dict() )  # -> {'this': 'is', 'more': 'clear'}
```