# Override list(object)

Tags: python-3.x

How do you override `list(object)` where `object` is an object defined by a class. Can you do something like

```
class foo:
    def __list__(self):
        return [None] # In my real code I want it to return a object
```

It would also be helpful if someone found a question with the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: "In my real code I want it to return a object" So return that object? It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve and what is stopping you from achieving that

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `__iter__` method to make your object iterable. `list` can then create results based on the resulting iterator. You can also use `yield` generator syntax:

```
class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield None

print(list(Foo())) # prints [None]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Also does list depend on___len____?

Comment: @RaymondPeng, no, it will accumulate all results of a generator, regardless of length.

Comment: By the way, this answer is actually pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627087/10818862