# magic method for passing object in function as argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

Is there any magic method that will invoke when I pass object as argument of function?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
    def __???__(self):
         return (self.a, self.b)

test = Test(0, 1)

some_function(test) # I'd like to pass parameters (0, 1) here
```

Comment: No, there isn’t. That would be super confusing. You can implement `__iter__` and call `some_function(*test)`, though.

Comment: There is no magic in Python. You may want to see Ruby for magic.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601389/4014959) by Python core dev Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: @ElisByberi Methods like `__len__`, `__add__` and `__repr__` are commonly referred to as "magic methods"

Comment: @PM2Ring Of course they call them magic. They use them to do tricks! I am still with "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @ElisByberi SO veteran Ned Batchelder coined another term for such methods (and attributes): [Dunder](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200605/dunder.html), perhaps you'd prefer that term.

Comment: @PM2Ring I prefer 'class init',  'class constructor',  'class initialization'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, arguments to functions are not treated special in any way. It's just another assignment (to the parameter names of the function).

If you need to treat `a` and `b` as separate arguments, make `Test` a *sequence*, then pass it in with the `*sequence` call syntax to expand the sequence to separate arguments. You can make it a sequence by making it an [iterator type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
    def __iter__(self):
         return iter((self.a, self.b))

test = Test(0, 1)
some_function(*test)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def some_function(a, b):
...     print(f'a = {a!r}\nb = {b!r}')
...
>>> test = Test(0, 1)
>>> some_function(*test)
a = 0
b = 1
```

Comment: Nice example of [PEP 498 f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) also.

Comment: I'm under the impression that f-string have to evaluate to a value.  Two questions, is some_function passing the value of self.a or is it actually passing the pointer and then it gets looked up at the print statement?  If a value will ultimately be passed to the f-string, what  is the advantage of using !r here?

Comment: @Rookie: yes, `f` strings specify expressions whose results are interpolated. The `str.format()` equivalent is `'a = {!r}\nb = {!r}'.format(a, b)`. `a` and `b` are just *local variables* in the `some_function()` function. You could give them different names if that helps your understanding better.