# Is Python dictionary unpacking customizable?

Tags: python, dictionary, argument-unpacking

Is there a dunder method which corresponds to using the dictionary unpacking opertator `**` on an object?

For example:

```python
class Foo():
    def __some_dunder__(self):
        return {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

foo = Foo()
assert {'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {**foo}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Are `a` and `b` the instance variables of `foo` or are they class variables? Where do those values come from? Or is that the hard coded dict you wanna throw out during unpacking?

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8601268/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to satisfy the constraint with two methods (Python 3.9) `__getitem__` and `keys()`:

```py
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, k): # <-- obviously, this is dummy implementation
        if k == "a":
            return 1

        if k == "b":
            return 2

    def keys(self):
        return ("a", "b")


foo = Foo()
assert {"a": 1, "b": 2} == {**foo}
```

---

For more complete solution you can subclass from [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) (Needs implementing 3 methods `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`)

Comment: That's hilarious. I just spent the last ~5 minutes doing the same and came to the exact same conclusion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it might be better to put that explanation of the implementation on the canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8601268/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Reworded and done. I've never seen that other post before.