# I get a AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable' when I try to install libraries using PIP

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

I just installed python3 on my new pc and tried to install some libraries (`numpy`, `cython`, `cymem`) using `pip` and I get

```
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
```

but libraries like `nltk` and `cytest` installed okay

Comment: add specific python and pip version info.

Comment: You must be more specific: which platform (Windows, Linux, ...etc). Which version of Python, what is the full error output.

Comment: python: 3.9.0a2

Comment: pip version: 19.3.1

Comment: @GeneralSags: Add the full error output. Which platform are you using? (Linux or Windows)?

Comment: Platform: Windows 10 (64 bit), 
Python:  64 bit (3.9.0a2)
Pip version: 19.3.1

Comment: Please edit your post and add the **Full error message** in the post.

Comment: Found this exact issue in GitHub:
https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3266

Answer (score 11):

collections.Iterable is deprecated.
Replace it with collections.abc.Iterable.

See this answer for compatibility :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53978543/13369176

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a problem usually occurring in library code not mine, the quick fix might be instead of

```
import collections
```

to write

```
import collections.abc as collections
```

and fill the bug in the repository of the respective project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do this:

```
import collections
collections.Iterable = collections.abc.Iterable
```

Found here: https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml/issues/91