# Python 3.10 Iterables Attribute change from 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error in Python3.10.6

```
    isinstance(pattern, collections.Iterable):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
```

in a significant and critical legacy program I didn't write (it's the buildsystem for another product). It worked fine with 3.8.10.  The error is breaking the build on GitHub CI under Linux. Seems like they upgraded Python a couple of days ago. Does anyone have a suggestion to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809785/i-get-a-attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-iterable-when-i

Comment: `collections.abc.Iterable`

Comment: ok thanks I think i get the problem, the code has to work on 3.8 AND 3.10, so just adding `abc` isn't going to work. There are many files in the program containing `import collections` and that still works.  Maybe `import collections.abc` and fallback to `import collections` if that fails?

Comment: ```try:
  collectionsIterable = collections.Iterable
except:
  collectionsIterable = collections.abc.Iterable
```
does this on 3.10 now `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'abc'` but it does work on 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code in python3.10 and python3.8 and it seems to work on both:

```
try:
    # python 3.10
    from collections.abc import Iterable
except ImportError:
    # if failed, fall back to python 3.8
    from collections import Iterable


pattern = [1, 2, 3]

print(isinstance(pattern, Iterable))
```

results :

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

collections.abc.Iterable works on both 3.8 and 3.10