# Merging dicts in dicts without overwriting the whole dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**I want to merge two nested dicts with each other**, sometimes they have the same amount of dicts in dicts sometimes not.

**By merging I mean I want to keep everything in my already existing .json file and only update the new changed values from my example dict `dict_01`.** If a key or whole dictionary does not exist, I want to add a new dict in dict if let's say 'name_03' does not yet exist.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


json_filepath = 'database.json'

dict_01 = {"database": {"name_01": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"},
                        "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"}}}



with open(json_filepath, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


pprint(data)
```

### This seems to only replace my current dict. Therefore all existing information is deleted. Not what I'm after.

```
data.update(dict_01)  # That doesn't do what I want it to do


with open(json_filepath, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data)
```

### Sample content of `database.json` file

```
{"database": {"name_01": {"count": 1,
                          "file_count": 1,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_01_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_01",
                          "server_path": "root.txt",
                          "size": "0.18"},
              "name_02": {"all_types_count": 4,
                          "file_count": 8,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_02_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_02",
                          "server_path": "...",
                          "size": "50.34"}}}
```

### The result I'm looking for:

```
{"database": {"name_01": {"count": 10,
                          "file_count": 1,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_01_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_01",
                          "server_path": "root.txt",
                          "size": "3"},
              "name_02": {"all_types_count": 4,
                          "file_count": 8,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_02_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_02",
                          "server_path": "...",
                          "size": "50.34"},
              "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                          "count": 10, 
                          "size": "3"}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For merging 2 dicts I would use this:

```
def mergedicts(dict1, dict2):
   for k in set(dict1.keys()).union(dict2.keys()):
       if k in dict1 and k in dict2:
          if isinstance(dict1[k], dict) and isinstance(dict2[k], dict):
             yield (k, dict(mergedicts(dict1[k], dict2[k])))
          else:
             yield (k, dict2[k])
       elif k in dict1:
           yield (k, dict1[k])
       else:
          yield (k, dict2[k])
```

and:

```
dict1 = {1:{"a":"A"},2:{"b":"B"}}
dict2 = {2:{"c":"C"},3:{"d":"D"}}
print dict(mergedicts(dict1,dict2))
```

Which prints:

```
{1: {'a': 'A'}, 2: {'c': 'C', 'b': 'B'}, 3: {'d': 'D'}}
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work without any errors! The only thing that seemed important is the order so I had to switch it to `dict(mergedicts(dict2,dict1)` with my data. I this that comes with in my case `dict1`is my `dict_01`.

Comment: Second line can nowadays be simplified to `for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys():`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_01["database"] = {**dict_01["database"], **dict_02["database"]}
```

I tested this.

Full working code:

```
dict_01 = {"database": {"name_01": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"},
                        "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"}}}

dict_02 = {"database": {"name_01": {"count": 1,
                          "file_count": 1,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_01_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_01",
                          "server_path": "root.txt",
                          "size": "0.18"},
              "name_02": {"all_types_count": 4,
                          "file_count": 8,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_02_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_02",
                          "server_path": "...",
                          "size": "50.34"}}}

dict_01["database"] = {**dict_01["database"], **dict_02["database"]} 
print(dict_01)
```

out:

```
{"database": {"name_01": {"count": 10,
                          "file_count": 1,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_01_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_01",
                          "server_path": "root.txt",
                          "size": "3"},
              "name_02": {"all_types_count": 4,
                          "file_count": 8,
                          "folder_count": 0,
                          "hdd_master_name": "name_02_suffix",
                          "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
                          "name": "name_02",
                          "server_path": "...",
                          "size": "50.34"},
              "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                          "count": 10, 
                          "size": "3"}}}
```

Comment: How will that help to update `data`? You're only working with `dict_01` and don't work with `data` at all?

Comment: Amit Davidson's answer worked for you, and it doesn't mention data. Label your variables. I think data might be the same as dict_02 in my answer. I'm adding my assumptions to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update ***data['database']*** not ***data***. Code goes as follows;

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_filepath = 'database.json'

dict_01 = {"database": {"name_01": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"},
                        "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"}}}



with open(json_filepath, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


# here is the change
data['database'].update(dict_01['database'])

pprint(data)

with open(json_filepath, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data)
```

Hope it helps. :) Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is still overwriting a lot of data. I want to only update or add new values. And with that method, a lot of keys and values are deleted.

Comment: Its still overwritting data means. I think you are trying to update parameters inside keys of database itself. Am i correct? For example you are trying to update `data['database']['name_01']` or so. Is is correct?

Comment: I think you need that way. Let give another Method to recursively update dictionary.

Comment: I have added an new answer, I think That will solve your purpose.

Comment: Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import collections
def dict_merge(dct, merge_dct):
    for k, v in merge_dct.items():
        if (k in dct and isinstance(dct[k], dict)
            and isinstance(merge_dct[k], collections.Mapping)):
            dict_merge(dct[k], merge_dct[k])
        else:
            dct[k] = merge_dct[k]
    return dct
```

*Full code*

```
import json
import collections

with open("database.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

dict_01 = {"database": {"name_01": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"},
                        "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"}}}

def dict_merge(dct, merge_dct):
    for k, v in merge_dct.items():
        if (k in dct and isinstance(dct[k], dict)
            and isinstance(merge_dct[k], collections.Mapping)):
            dict_merge(dct[k], merge_dct[k])
        else:
            dct[k] = merge_dct[k]
    return dct

out = dict_merge(data, dict_01)
print(out)
# {
#     "database": {
#         "name_01": {
#             "count": 10,
#             "file_count": 1,
#             "folder_count": 0,
#             "hdd_master_name": "name_01_suffix",
#             "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
#             "name": "name_01",
#             "server_path": "root.txt",
#             "size": "3"
#         },
#         "name_02": {
#             "all_types_count": 4,
#             "file_count": 8,
#             "folder_count": 0,
#             "hdd_master_name": "name_02_suffix",
#             "last_scanned": "14/04/20 15:55",
#             "name": "name_02",
#             "server_path": "...",
#             "size": "50.34"
#         },
#         "name_03": {
#             "name": "name_01",
#             "count": 10,
#             "size": "3"
#         }
#     }
# }
```

Source: [Recursive dictionary merge in Python](https://gist.github.com/angstwad/bf22d1822c38a92ec0a9)

Comment: Thank you this seems to work well. I only get following warning. `DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working` `and isinstance(merge_dct[k], collections.Mapping)):` Do you know anything about that?

Comment: You can try replacing the `import collections` by `import collections.abc as collections`. This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978542/how-to-use-collections-abc-from-both-python-3-8-and-python-2-7) deals with this deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

@BenjaminK

If you need to update data recursively; for example;
if `db` is:

```
db_01 = {"database": {"name_01": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"},
                        "name_03": {"name": "name_01",
                                    "count": 10, 
                                    "size": "3"}}}
```

and dictionary you want to update is;

```
dict_to_update = {"database": {"name_03": {"father":{"name":"john"}}}}
```

The you need to do like following;

For ***Python2.X***;

```
import collections

def update(db, dict2update):
    for k, v in dict2update.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            db[k] = update(db.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            db[k] = v
    return d
```

For ***Python3.X***;

```
import collections.abc

def update(db, dict2update):
    for k, v in dict2update.items():
        if isinstance(v, collections.abc.Mapping):
            db[k] = update(db.get(k, {}), v)
        else:
            db[k] = v
    return db
```

You can update your database `db_01` like following;

`update(db_01, dict_01)`

After doing this your db_01 will be;

```
{'database': {'name_01': {'name': 'name_01', 'count': 10, 'size': '3'},
  'name_03': {'name': 'name_01',
   'count': 10,
   'size': '3',
   'father': {'name': 'john'}}}}
```

Hope this helps. If not let me know. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Check this out.