# DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of fr om 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working

Tags: python, collections, manage.py, django-manage.py

I downloaded a code from github and trying to run it as it is by running command in git bash: `python manage.py runserver`

But I am experiencing this error:

```
DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
```

Have made changes to my manage.py file as suggested in this answer [How to use collections.abc from both Python 3.8+ and Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978542/how-to-use-collections-abc-from-both-python-3-8-and-python-2-7)
but still facing the same error.

```
import os
import sys

try:
    from collections.abc import Callable
except ImportError:
    from collections import Callable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Basic DJango tutorial fails at `py manage.py runserver` with this same error.

Answer (score 1):

The `DeprecationWarning` is arising from imports occurring within django itself.
This is a known issue in older versions of Django:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30078

It has since been fixed:
https://github.com/django/django/commit/aba9763b5117494ca1ef1e420397e3845ad5b262

Based on the release tags for that commit, it appears that the fix first appeared in Django version 2.1.

The solution is to use a newer version of Django.

Comment: I am getting these warning while runing test cases in flask. not using django