# I was trying to test my code getting this pytest error

Tags: pytest

def test_login():
print("Login to application")

```
def test_checkout():
    print("Checkout")

    def test_logout():
        print("Logout From application")
```

> **warnings summary**
> ....\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:19
> C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py:19: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collect
> ions.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
> return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)

Comment: That's a warning, not an error (so your tests should pass despite the message), and it seems pretty clear. Are you having trouble understanding the warning message?

Comment: As mentioned above, just a deprecation warning. "In Python 3.3 "abstract base classes" in collections (like MutableMapping or MutableSequence) were moved to second-level module collections.abc.", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978542/how-to-use-collections-abc-from-both-python-3-8-and-python-2-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Pytest docs related to warning](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html).

> By default pytest will display `DeprecationWarning` and `PendingDeprecationWarning` warnings from user code and third-party libraries, as recommended by PEP-0565. This helps users keep their code modern and avoid breakages when deprecated warnings are effectively removed.

In your case, it seems to come from a third party library (`pyreadline`) that is importing `collections` in a way that will not be supported anymore in Python `3.10`. So you may upgrade the library if a further version fixes this import or choose to disable or filter this warning in Pytest. In this case, you will find in the [Pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html) a set of gradual options to do so.